# Heat equation in a three dimensional ball (for a Fourier analysis class)

Tags: fourier-analysis, heat-equation

I need help with the heat eqn in a three dimensional ball - I'm completely lost:

[given equation, boundary conditions, and radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2VTX.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please be specific in your question as to where you are having difficulty, and try to explain what you know and have tried.

Comment: Hi, it wants us to solve the heat equation given in the picture, but I don't even know where to start cause I don't really understand what it being asked

Comment: Here's a hint: notice that the equation is spherically symmetric, so try to transform the equation so that it is one dimensional rather than three dimensional.

Comment: so convert x,y,z to r